# InteliJ SBT auto import of scala project gives: Binary incompatibility in plugins detected

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, java-8, scala-2.11

I was working happily in InteliJ with scala 2.10 and Java 1.7 - and am in the process of trying to upgrade to scala 2.11 and Java 1.8

I'm on Ubuntu 14 -- and javac shows

```
update-alternatives --config javac
There are 2 choices for the alternative javac (providing /usr/bin/javac).

  Selection    Path                                  Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac   4         auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javac   3         manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac   4         manual mode
```

As I have both java 7 and 8 installed.

I'm trying to import a Play 2.3 project (using the IntelJ SBT auto import) and am getting the error

```
Error while importing SBT project: ... at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20) at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala) [error] sbt.IncompatiblePluginsException: Binary incompatibility in plugins detected. [error] Note that conflicts were resolved for some dependencies: [error] com.github.mpeltonen:sbt-idea [error] commons-io:commons-io [error] org.apache.commons:commons-lang3
......
```

I'm not sure how to progress investigating this; but my thinking is

From - [Sbt plugin binary incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144618/sbt-plugin-binary-incompatibility) - it could relate to the version on SBT that inteliJ is using?

Another thought was; Is the InteliJ Scala Plugin specific to a Java version (7 vs 8?) If so - how do I make sure InteliJ gets the correct one? I tried re-installing the plugin; but that didn't change anything.

Thanks
Brent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah; I just had to update Project Settings to use 1.8!